# Polygon how to know if vertex moving on google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon

I'm using drawing manager to draw polygon.

I want to display live moving data on polygon vertex.

I have tried used two methods below.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), 'set_at', processVertex);
google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), 'insert_at',processVertex);
```

But its call after vertex end moving/ drag end.
i want something while moving ...

I have this fiddle and data i'm displaying.

http://jsfiddle.net/subhashchavda/6a8db64z/65/

I want something like this

```
 listener(polygon.getPath(), 'vertex_drag',function(){
     update_data(); /* dragging/moving */
 });
```

Is there any way /trick for listen vertex dragging ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no in build  function available in google map doc. so right now if want to it to workout you can use custom code like listening vertax click and drag on map.

Here is some code you can try with that.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'mousedown', function(e){
     if(e.vertex){
          // flag for vertax drag start
     }
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function(e){
     if(e.vertex){
          // flag for vertax dragging
     }
});

google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'mouseup', function(e){
     if(e.vertex){
          // flag for vertax drag stop
     }
});
```

But i'm not sure it will work with every conditions.

you need to more workout with this code.

Comment: Thnks.. its not perfect but very usefull. i have now idea to how i can fix it.